# Is Google API for .NET (version 2) Redistributable?

Tags: .net, api, installation

I made a small product using Google APIs.
Now i need to sell it to my client.

I made installer and simply added all APIs.
But now it is showing error of type COM.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: If you use word _redistributable_ in context of 3rd party software package, everyone's going to think it's about legal meaning of this term. Software package or another part of authoring tool is redistributable if you can legally redistribute it to your clients. For example MS Visual C++ 2008 contains redistributable package with C++ runtime libraries which you can deliver to your users with your software. The same for .NET framework. That's why you're getting answers about Google API licence instead of hint how to solve your technical problems.

Comment: If you want help resolving problems with your installer, you need to a) reformulate question to get rid of misleading words (redistributable) and b) add more details: What Google API? Version? Link? Have you built it, or have you used some pre-built binaries? With what compiler have you built your program? Version? Which version of .NET (or Mono)? On what operating system are you testing your installer? How have you created the installer? With what tool? Version? And most importatntly: __What exactly the error message said? I mean _exactly_!__

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/ then thats under a mit license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php which means you can distribute it as long as the copyright text is included with the software.

Answer (score 0):

have you copied all the dll's on the target system (and if needed registered them)?

what is the exact message and err-code you get from your managed exception?

Answer (score 0):

It is zero hassle redistributable if you just take and redistribute the binaries (actual dlls as published by Google) since in that case you are legally just using the binary.

If you compile the code for these dlls-s on your own or do any changes to their source then you are going to need a lawyer :-). MIT License is not infective but would still require attribution for a derivative work.

If you are going to have your own licensing text in your package than you should add a simple line like:

*[Uses libraries made by iron9light and provided under MIT License]*

That's attribution - big word for a little line :-)